# How to create a custom maven phase, that will not be run during build?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, lifecycle

I would like a plugin to only be run during a new phase.  Mainly, I don't want the plugin to run during the build lifecycle.

Something like install:
maven clean build custom:meOnly

GC

Note: I am attempting to call this plug-in:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>runbatchfile</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>deploy.bat</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins consist of *goals*. If you don't bind a goal to a lifecycle phase, it will not be executed during build. You can, though, start it as `plugin:goal` from the command line.

There is no need to create an additional phase, a goal will do just fine.

Comment: Can you include a code sample of not binding it to a phase?

Comment: Just erase the `<executions>` part.

Comment: Is it clear to you now, or do you need further clarification?

Comment: Not completely, if i remove the goal, how do I call it?

Comment: `exec:exec` from the command line, e.g. `mvn clean deploy exec:exec`.